# ¿Error al tratar de Filtrar datos en Django?

Tags: python, django

el problema que me muestra ala hora de tratar de filtra datos con django me sale este error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi vista es la siguente:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from functools import reduce  
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, ListView, DeleteView
from .models import Identificador 


class RBMidentificadorListView(ListView):
    model = Identificador
    template_name = 'identificadores/lista.html'
    context_object_name = 'lista_identificador'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(RBMidentificadorListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['search_url'] = 'lsitar_identificado'
        return ctx

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(RBMidentificadorListView, self).get_queryset()
        # En el admin_base.jade tenemos un input#search(name='q', type='search')
        # usamos la sig linea para obtener la consulta solicitada.
        q = self.request.GET.getlist('q')
        terms = [term for term in q]
        if q:  # Si el campo no esta vacio, construimos el filtro
            queryset = reduce(operator.or_,
                (Identificador.objects.filter(Q(clave__contains=t) \
                    | Q(nombre__contains=t)) \
                    for t in terms
                )
            )
        return queryset
```

urls:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^new/$', RBMidentificadorView.as_view(), name='register_identificador'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RBMidentificadoresEditView.as_view(), name='editar_identificador'),
    url(r'^list/$', RBMidentificadorListView.as_view(), name='lsitar_identificador'),
    url(r'^dele/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RBMidentificadorDeleView.as_view(), name='eliminar_identificador'),
]
```

html:

```
{% if search_url %}
    <li> <!-- solo donde se tengan registros-->
        <form action='{% url search_url %}' method="get">
            <div class="input-field">
                <input id="search" type="search" name='q'>
                <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
                <i class="material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
        </form>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de identacion.

Prueba asi:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from functools import reduce
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, ListView, DeleteView
from .models import Identificador


class RBMidentificadorListView(ListView):
    model = Identificador
    template_name = 'identificadores/lista.html'
    context_object_name = 'lista_identificador'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(RBMidentificadorListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['search_url'] = 'lsitar_identificado'
        return ctx


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(RBMidentificadorListView, self).get_queryset()
        # En el admin_base.jade tenemos un input#search(name='q', type='search')
        # usamos la sig linea para obtener la consulta solicitada.
        q = self.request.GET.getlist('q')
        terms = [term for term in q]
        if q:  # Si el campo no esta vacio, construimos el filtro
            queryset = reduce(operator.or_,
                              (Identificador.objects.filter(Q(clave__contains=t)
                                                            | Q(nombre__contains=t))
                               for t in terms
                               )
                              )
        return queryset
```

Si estas usando SublineText usa `view > indentation > convert indentation to tabs` a veces los bloques no estan al mismo nivel pese a estar bien escritos, es un error comun.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773271/how-to-fix-convert-space-indentation-in-sublime-text

Comment: Gracias amigo, me ayudo mucho y reparo el error. gracias y saludos.

Comment: De nada! Me alegro que te haya servido de ayuda ;)